# generate a list of numbers with increasing digit order

Tags: haskell

Hi I am trying to generate a list with

- All possible `n` digit numbers
- And their digits are in decreasing order

For example, if `n = 3` the output will be [111 .. 321 .. 543 ..999].

My initial attempt was

```hs
--attempt1

digits n = map (\x -> read [x] :: Int) (show n)

sorted [] = True
sorted [x] = True
sorted (x:y:xs) = if x <= y then sorted (y:xs) else False


[ x | x <- [ 10^(n-1) .. 10^n ] , sorted $ digits $ x]
```

However this approach got slower exponentially as the variable n got bigger.

My second approach was (if n == 3)

```hs
joiner :: [Integer] -> Integer
joiner = read . concatMap show

[ joiner [z,y,x] |
        x <- [1..9],
        y <- [9,8..x],
        z <- [9,8..y]]
```

However now the problem is how I can generalise this code to an arbitrary `n`

```hs
joiner :: [Integer] -> Integer
joiner = read . concatMap show

[ joiner [a_n,...,a_1] |
        a_1 <- [1..9],
        a_2 <- [9,8..x],
        .
        .
        .
        a_n <- [9,8..a_n-1]
]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every time you need to combine N of something (where N is unknown upfront), the answer is always recursion. After all, that's the only way to iterate in Haskell.

First, we'll need a way to append another digit to a given number. Simple enough:

```
appendDigit x = [ x*10 + d | d <- [0..9] ]
```

Let's test it out:

```
λ appendDigit 2
[20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29]
λ appendDigit 3                
[30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39]
```

But not good enough: we only need to append digits that are *less than the last one*. Well, easy to modify:

```
appendDigit x = [ x*10 + d | d <- [0..(lastDigit-1)] ]
    where lastDigit = x `mod` 10
```

Try it out:

```
λ appendDigit 2          
[20,21]                  
*Main Lib                
λ appendDigit 3          
[30,31,32]               
*Main Lib                
λ appendDigit 8          
[80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87]
```

And now all that remains is just to do it N times, concatenating resulting lists along the way:

```
decDigits 0 = []  -- degenerate case: when N = 0, there are no such numbers
decDigits 1 = [0..9] -- base case: N = 1
decDigits n = concatMap appendDigit $ decDigits (n-1)
```